# Anchors not working on search results page using woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, anchor

I am developing a site for a client using Wordpress and Woocommerce and have an issue where I can not click on any of the anchors on the search results page.

The search results page is here: http://79.170.44.83/newcityused.com/?s=chair

I can see nothing in the CSS that would make this happen.
I have deactivated all of the plugins with no joy.
I'm lost.

Has anyone else experienced this or know of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class .search inside your 'body' tag and then you have a js that is something like this:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.search').on('click', function(e) {
  jQuery('.search-form').toggleClass("expand");
  e.preventDefault();
 });

})
```

I think that you are preventing the default clicks in here... so remove the e.preventDefault it made work, let me know...